# How do I collapse an Active Record query into one active record set (NOT using flatten)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Using flatten turns the data into an array

I want to do

```
run.schedule_locations.collect { |sl| sl.schedule_machines }
```

but when I do, each result in the array is an array

```
=> [
  [0] [
    [0] #<ScheduleMachine:0x007f94c3e6bce8> {
```

I want to get a single active record query that I can then loop through, treating each item as an active-record enabled ScheduleMachine.

How do I do this?

Comment: how do you create this hash/array ?

Comment: What? I showed the code I ran. run is an instance of a class.

Comment: i meant the `schedule_locations` it self, what does it return ? cause if it was a normal array, ull have  a normal schedule_machine array, but somehow you have a nested array